# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 255 and 108 for '{{node SquaredDifference}}

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, yolov4

I am trying to train a YoloV4 model with my own data.
I get the following error when i try to fit the model with a custom loss function:

```
ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 2945760 elements to shape [2,76,76,3,36] (1247616 elements)
```

the parameters are:

```
NETWORK_W        = 608
NETWORK_H        = 608
NB_BOX           = 3
NB_CLASS         = len(labels)
OBJ_THRESHOLD    = 0.3
NMS_THRESHOLD    = 0.3
grids = [(76,76), (38,38), (19,19)]
anchors = [ [12, 16, 19, 36, 40, 28],[36, 75, 76, 55, 72, 146],[142, 110, 192, 243, 459, 401]]
scales_x_y = [1.2, 1.1, 1.05]
NO_OBJECT_SCALE  = 1.0
OBJECT_SCALE     = 5.0
COORD_SCALE      = 1.0
CLASS_SCALE      = 1.0

BATCH_SIZE       = 2
TRUE_BOX_BUFFER  = 50
```

the loss function looks like this:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    grid_h, grid_w = y_pred.shape[1:3] 
    
    if grid_h == grids[0][0]:
        anchor = anchors[0]
    elif grid_h == grids[1][0]: 
        anchor = anchors[1]
    else:    
        anchor = anchors[2]     
    print("anchor",anchor)    
   
    mask_shape = tf.shape(y_true)[:4]
    
    cell_x = tf.cast((tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(grid_w), [grid_h]), (1, grid_h, grid_w, 1, 1))),dtype=tf.float32)
    cell_y = tf.transpose(cell_x, (0,2,1,3,4))
    cell_grid = tf.tile(tf.concat([cell_x,cell_y], -1), [BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, NB_BOX, 1])
    
    ######  prediction
    y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, (BATCH_SIZE, grid_h, grid_w, NB_BOX, NB_CLASS+5))
    print ("prediction", y_pred.shape)
    
    ### adjust x and y  
    pred_box_xy = tf.sigmoid(y_pred[..., :2]) # x, y)
    pred_box_xy = pred_box_xy + cell_grid
    
    ### adjust w and h
    pred_box_wh = tf.exp(y_pred[..., 2:4]) * np.reshape(anchor, [1,1,1,NB_BOX,2]) / np.full((1,1,1,NB_BOX, 2), [NETWORK_W, NETWORK_H])

    
    ### adjust objectness
    pred_box_obj = tf.sigmoid(y_pred[..., 4])
    
    ### adjust class probabilities
    pred_box_class = tf.sigmoid(y_pred[..., 5:])
    
    
    ######  true
    y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, (BATCH_SIZE, grid_h, grid_w, NB_BOX, NB_CLASS+5))
    print ("true", y_true.shape)

    ### adjust x and y  
    true_box_xy = y_true[..., :2] # x, y
    
    ### adjust w and h
    true_box_wh = y_true[..., 2:4]
    
    ### adjust objectness
    true_wh_half = true_box_wh / 2.
    true_mins    = true_box_xy - true_wh_half
    true_maxes   = true_box_xy + true_wh_half

    pred_wh_half = pred_box_wh / 2.
    pred_mins    = pred_box_xy - pred_wh_half
    pred_maxes   = pred_box_xy + pred_wh_half       

    intersect_mins  = tf.maximum(pred_mins,  true_mins)
    intersect_maxes = tf.minimum(pred_maxes, true_maxes)
    intersect_wh    = tf.maximum(intersect_maxes - intersect_mins, 0.)
    
    intersect_areas = intersect_wh[..., 0] * intersect_wh[..., 1]
    true_areas = true_box_wh[..., 0] * true_box_wh[..., 1]
    pred_areas = pred_box_wh[..., 0] * pred_box_wh[..., 1]

    union_areas = pred_areas + true_areas - intersect_areas + 1e-10
    iou_scores  = tf.truediv(intersect_areas, union_areas)
   
    true_box_obj = iou_scores * y_true[..., 4]
    
    ### adjust class probabilities
    true_box_class = tf.argmax(y_true[..., 5:], -1)

    
    
    ######  coefficients   
   
    ### coordinate mask: simply the position of the ground truth boxes (the predictors)
    ### is 1 when there is an object in the cell i, else 0.
    coord_mask = tf.zeros(mask_shape)
    coord_mask = tf.expand_dims(y_true[..., 4], axis=-1) * COORD_SCALE
    
    ### objectness mask: penelize predictors + penalize boxes with low IOU
    # penalize the confidence of the boxes, which have IOU with some ground truth box < 0.6
    for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        bd = y_true[i,:,:,:,:4]
        nozero = tf.not_equal(bd, tf.zeros((grid_h, grid_w, NB_BOX, 4)))
        bdd = tf.boolean_mask(bd, nozero)
        s=tf.squeeze(tf.size(bdd)//4)
        c= tf.zeros((50-s,4))
        bdd=tf.reshape(bdd, (s,4))
        bdd = tf.concat([bdd,c],axis=0)
        bdd = tf.expand_dims(bdd,0)
        bdd = tf.expand_dims(bdd,0)
        bdd = tf.expand_dims(bdd,0)
        bdd = tf.expand_dims(bdd,0)
        if (i==0):
            true_boxes =bdd
        else:
            true_boxes = tf.concat([true_boxes,bdd], axis=0)  
    
    true_xy = true_boxes[..., 0:2]
    true_wh = true_boxes[..., 2:4]
    true_wh_half = true_wh / 2.
    true_mins    = true_xy - true_wh_half
    true_maxes   = true_xy + true_wh_half
    
    pred_xy = tf.expand_dims(pred_box_xy, 4)
    pred_wh = tf.expand_dims(pred_box_wh, 4)
    
    pred_wh_half = pred_wh / 2.
    pred_mins    = pred_xy - pred_wh_half
    pred_maxes   = pred_xy + pred_wh_half    
    
    intersect_mins  = tf.maximum(pred_mins,  true_mins)
    intersect_maxes = tf.minimum(pred_maxes, true_maxes)
    intersect_wh    = tf.maximum(intersect_maxes - intersect_mins, 0.)
    intersect_areas = intersect_wh[..., 0] * intersect_wh[..., 1]
    
    true_areas = true_wh[..., 0] * true_wh[..., 1]
    pred_areas = pred_wh[..., 0] * pred_wh[..., 1]

    union_areas = pred_areas + true_areas - intersect_areas
    iou_scores  = tf.truediv(intersect_areas, union_areas)
    best_ious = tf.reduce_max(iou_scores, axis=4)
    
    obj_mask = tf.zeros(mask_shape)
    obj_mask = tf.cast((best_ious < 0.6),dtype=tf.float32) * (1 - y_true[..., 4]) * NO_OBJECT_SCALE
    obj_mask = obj_mask + y_true[..., 4] * OBJECT_SCALE

    
    ### class mask: simply the position of the ground truth boxes (the predictors)
    ### is 1 when there is a particular class is predicted, else 0.
    class_mask = tf.zeros(mask_shape)
    class_weights = np.ones(NB_CLASS, dtype='float32')
    class_mask = y_true[..., 4] * tf.gather(class_weights, true_box_class) * CLASS_SCALE
    
    nb_coord_box = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((coord_mask > 0.0),dtype=tf.float32))
    nb_obj_box  = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((obj_mask  > 0.0),dtype=tf.float32))
    nb_class_box = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((class_mask > 0.0),dtype=tf.float32))
      
    ### loss
    loss_xy    = tf.reduce_sum(coord_mask * tf.square(true_box_xy - pred_box_xy)) / (nb_coord_box + 1e-6) / 2.
    loss_wh    = tf.reduce_sum(coord_mask * tf.square(tf.sqrt(tf.abs(true_box_wh)) - tf.sqrt(tf.abs(pred_box_wh)))) / (nb_coord_box + 1e-6) / 2.
    loss_obj   = tf.reduce_sum(obj_mask * tf.square(true_box_obj-pred_box_obj)) / (nb_obj_box + 1e-6) / 2.
    loss_class = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=true_box_class, logits=pred_box_class)
    loss_class = tf.reduce_sum(class_mask * loss_class) / (nb_class_box + 1e-6)
    
    loss = loss_xy + loss_wh + loss_obj + loss_class
    print()
    return loss
```

I changed the

`y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, (BATCH_SIZE, grid_h, grid_w, NB_BOX, NB_CLASS+5))`

to:

`y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, (BATCH_SIZE, grid_h, grid_w, NB_BOX, -1))`

But i get the following error :

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 255 and 108 for '{{node SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](Yolo_v4/BN_138/FusedBatchNormV3, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [2,76,76,255], [2,76,76,108].
```

Now i'm not sure where it goes wrong, my data should be fine and i believe the the problem is in the custom loss, but i dont know where.

Any tips would be appreciated!